# Migrating from jQuery 1.9.1 to 1.10.1 causing error: Object has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, compatibility, uislider

1. [View my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/64kPm/)
2. Resize HTML preview to small width and see that slideshow is resized properly
3. Change jQuery from 1.9.1 to 1.10.1 (in left pane) and click RUN
4. Resize HTML preview to a small or large width
5. Open console, and see error: `Object [object Object] has no method 'bjqs'`

I cannot figure out what about the bjqs plugin is causing this problem with 1.10.1.

Is there something about the plugin preventing it from working the 2nd time it's called in the resize function?

JavaScript is included here, but jsFiddle linked above is going to be a better place to view it.

Plugin I am using is: http://www.basic-slider.com/

```
$(function () {

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
        this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function () {
            slideShow(); // re-init on resize stop
        }, 500);
    });

    function slideShow() {
        $('.bjqs-controls, .bjqs-markers').remove();
        console.log($(window).width());

        var ss_width;
        var ss_height;

        if ($(window).width() >= 600) {
            // Desktop
            ss_width = 300;
            ss_height = 200;
        } else if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            // Tablet
            ss_width = 150;
            ss_height = 150;
        }

        // Load content slideshow
        $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
            nexttext: 'Next',
            prevtext: 'Prev',
            showmarkers: true,
            centermarkers: true, // horizontally center markers            
            responsive: false, // enable responsive behaviour
            width: ss_width,
            height: ss_height
        });
    }

    // Init slide show on load
    slideShow();

});
```

Comment: Something in the JSFiddle is actually loading a _second_ instance of jQuery when you change it over to 1.10.1.  If you use Chrome DevTools and inspect the resources loaded on the fiddle page you'll see a version of jQuery pop in(1.10.2) from assets.pinsightmedia.com that is not there when you use 1.9.x.  The error is probably because the slider plugin is loading into one instance but not the other.

Comment: the lightbox plugin doesn't support jQuery 1.10 because it sees it as jquery 1.1 instead and loads in it's own version of jquery, completely breaking everything. terrible plugin design imo.

Comment: The root cause of the error within said plugin is `/^\d\.\d+/i.exec(jQuery.fn.jquery))<1.6` it compares the string 1.10 to 1.6 using alphanumeric sorting, therefore 1.6 > "1.10", so it includes it's own version and doesn't properly prevent conflicts.

Comment: Kevin, nice freaking catch. Please convert your comment to an answer so I can award the points.

Comment: @KevinB can you convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: Sorry, i guess i missed your previous request for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the error within said plugin is `/^\d\.\d+/i.exec(jQuery.fn.jquery))<1.6` it compares the string "1.10" to "1.6" using alphanumeric sorting, therefore "1.6" > "1.10", so it includes it's own version and doesn't properly prevent conflicts. I'd suggest reporting this as a bug to the plugin author, it should be trivial to fix.